# Using run leads to different folder in Windows 10

Tags: windows, git, bash

Might be a silly question:
Why using Windows 10 run to start `git-bash.exe`, leads to a different folder than starting `git-bash.exe` on its own?

`Windows + R > Open: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git-bash.exe"` leads to: `username@ComputerName MINGW32 /` and if I need to go to my home folder, I need to `cd` then `enter`

Double click on the same `git-bash.exe` file leads to: `username@ComputerName MINGW32 ~ (master)` and I'm already in the home folder, using `cd` won't move to another folder.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, in Windows 10 what I see is that using the run dialog with an absolute path sets the working directory to that of the file, but if it has to search `PATH`, it sets the working directory to the user profile directory instead.

Comment: @eryksun, right you are, my mistake.

Comment: When I run "git-bash.exe" from the folder and with the run dialog using "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" (note, 64-bit, unlike the OP), it runs bash.exe in "/", i.e. "C:\Program Files\Git". But if I simply run "git-bash.exe" in the run dialog, it executes bash in "~", i.e. the user's profile directory. In both cases all 3 running executables (git-bash.exe, cmd.exe, and bash.exe) share the same working directory, according to Process Explorer, i.e. all  are "C:\Program Files\Git" in the first case and all are the user profile directory in the second case.